# How to get Get Attributes and NameID from encrypted SAML Response

Tags: laravel-5, saml-2.0, onelogin

I am working on OneLogin `SAML`, I am getting an encrypted response from onelogin, I am able to decrypt it from https://www.samltool.com/attributes.php, I am getting proper data in an array, but how to do that programmatically ? can anyone please help me how to do that?

Comment: Have you given SP's certificate to OneLogin? If you have configured SP using file or link it is possible that OneLogin as picked the certificate from it and encrypted the response. If you want to change it to only Signing of the response then you can do that by scrolling down in Configuration tab. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the [OneLogin’s SAML PHP Toolkit](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/tree/master/lib/Saml2) , Or you can use [Laravel-onelogin](https://github.com/ziffmedia/laravel-onelogin) package for allowing onelogin to provide authentication and users to your application.

If you are looking specifically for decryption. The below link has all encryption and decryption methods
https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/blob/master/extlib/xmlseclibs/xmlseclibs.php